# Bootstrap, HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’ve tried reading and studying Bootstrap, but I never seem to understand or get what the author’s saying. Could anyone be of assistence?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can probably help you but, you need to be a bit more specific on what you need help understanding.

If you need explanations of what each tag does I'd recommend looking for the tag in w3schools. It is a fantastic website with tons of information.

This is the bootstrap section of w3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

This is the html section for w3: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: Thanks. I sure would look into w3schools.